# Visual Studio c#: Zoom on a panel

Tags: c#, visual-studio, zooming, panel

In a visual Studio 2015 comunity project I have a panel (with some other controls on it) wihch is much larger (4000 x 3000px) than my viewport (screen).
Is there a way to make the panel zoomable?

Comment: Use [Left Ctrl] + [Mouse Wheel]

Comment: What Technology are you using, WinForms or WPF? Do you want zoom in the Visual Studio Designer or in the resulting project?

Comment: I'm unsing WinForms and want to zoom in the resulting project.